# Use of cp mv functions and ../

Tags: bash

I've stumbled into a code and am questioning whether I understand what is being done:

```
cp $i ../../$x/$y
```

Does this copy the values of i two directories up from the directories /$x/$y for each i? (this was in a for loop.)

```
mv dir ../../$x$y/name
```

I think this moves the directory dir two directories up from $x$y/name. Is this correct? I have been having doubts understanding the syntax of bash when playing around with long directories.

Comment: `../` means the directory right above the *current* directory. So `../../$x/$y` would mean move up, move up, move down into $x, move down into $y.

Comment: So the first one copies the values of i into y and the second moves dir into name?

Answer (score 2):

This copies the file from the path in `i` variable to the mentioned directory.

`../../` means "two levels up".

`$x/$y` means move down to directory, which name is stored in the `x` variable, then move down to the directory from `y` variable.

But if `$y` directory doesn't exist, the file will be copied to `$y` file in the `$x` directory.

`mv dir ../../$x$y/name` moves `dir` to `name` located two levels up and two down `$x$y` -> `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Before beginning explanation, let say that `x` is `1` and `y` is `2`, and we used our command inside `/home/<user>/dir1/dir11/` folder.

Your 1st command is a usual `cp` command. You would copied your filename from `/home/<user>/dir1/dir11/`, and move it :

- by 2 folders up with 2 calls of `../`, so you're in `/home/<user>/`
- then by 2 folders down, named respectively as said inside `x` and `y` (so you copied it inside `/home/<user>/$x/$y/`, so it's `/home/<user>/1/2/` in our example)

NB : if `/home/<user>/1/2/` didn't exist, your copied file would take the name defined in `y`, so your file would be named `2`;  but if `/home/<user>/1/` didn't exist, `cp` command would fail and you would get an error

---

2nd command is a usual `mv` command. You would move the `dir` folder from `/home/<user>/dir1/dir11/` :

- as said for `cp` command, by 2 folders up, so you're in `/home/<user>/` due to 2 `../` usage
- then by 2 folders down, at 1st in `$x$y/` (which is `12/` in our example) and then `name/`. So your folder `dir` is placed like that : `/home/<user>/12/name/dir`